# Extracting Information from websites

Tags: java, html, html-content-extraction

Not every website exposes their data well, with XML feeds, APIs, etc

How could I go about extracting information from a website? For example:

```
...
<div>
  <div>
    <span id="important-data">information here</span>
  </div>
</div>
...
```

I come from a background of Java programming and coding with Apache XMLBeans. Is there anything similar to parse HTML, when I know the structure and the data is between a known tag?

Thanks

Comment: Be careful when doing this type of thing, especially if you intend hitting loads of pages on the same site and scraping them all for data. This can have a negative effect on that websites performance and is not very friendly.

Comment: I totally agree, I'm not interested in scraping, but there are times when you need to access data on sites,

Note, Java is not a must have, just a perference

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several Open Source HTML Parsers out there for Java.

I have used [JTidy](http://jtidy.sourceforge.net/) in the past, and have had good luck with it.  It will give you a DOM of the html page, and you should be able to grab the tags you need from there.

Answer (score 4):

[Here's an article](http://www.manageability.org/blog/stuff/screen-scraping-tools-written-in-java) that has a couple of screen scraping tools written in java.

In general, it sounds like you want to take a look at [regular expressions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/), which do the pattern matching you're looking for.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

Java seems like a fairly difficult constraint for such a task. Is that a hard requirement?  Scripting languages are ideal for building what is really lots of last-mile code.

If you're be open to it, ruby + [hpricot](http://code.whytheluckystiff.net/hpricot/) makes that completely trivial.  You can use css or xpath selectors (or both) to find (and manipulate) the content in HTML.  Grabbing the document, parsing it, and extracting the text in your example is literally one line of code.